# PayPal does not return transaction information

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to integrate PayPal on my site and I have problems with receiving information from PayPal about transaction.

I'm using sandbox environment for tests.

I generated the form and placed return url into there:

```
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='my-local-site/success.php'>
```

After all payments are done (and they are done correct - I'm getting money to my account) I'm returned to my-local-site/success.php without any parameters about this transaction.

I tried to make it like here - http://www.dollarfry.com/paypal-integration-guide-php/ but it does not work for me.

My question is why I don't receive any information about transaction from PayPal as payments were done correctly via sandbox (money were sent from one account to another correctly).

I want to get some info like

```
http://my.local.site/success.php?tx=6BC88318RN685282M&st=Completed&amt=20.00&cc=USD&cm=&item_number=BEAR05
```

What should I do to get that info? Is something wrong I do, or with my account?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an extra parameter.

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="0" />
```

Check PayPal's HTML variables documentation for more details.  Search for "return method" on that page and you should find it easily.

Comment: No, it does not work. I also set IPN configurations and added notify_url to my form but I don't receive any callback from PayPal.

Comment: So which are you trying to use then?  IPN or PDT.  They're two different things.